# Windows Installer Setup Project does not accept output from VSTO Excel add-in project due to supposed architecture mismatch

Tags: windows-installer, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins, comaddin

I am migrating an old Excel add-in from 32 to 64 bits. Orignal source code was lost so I need to repackage VBA files from an old MSI cabinet. I want to build a package (MSI) that contains:

- Updated Excel files from the old plugin (XLAM, XLA and some others)
- New VSTO Excell add-in that will load the VBA modules to Excell on startup.

I have configured a Windows Installer Setup Project to package output from the Add-in. [image]
[image]

Problem is that I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: File 'VSTOAddIn.dll' of project output 'Primary output from VSTOAddIn (Active)' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'.
```

I have set any drop down with architecture I found in both project configuration to "x64". In the build manager it seems like the Installer Setup Project is architecure agnostic:
[image]

Am I missing somthing or my approach is wrong alltogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit versions of Office will use the 64-bit registry hive to look for Add-ins. To register Add-ins under the 64-bit registry hive, the setup project's target platform must be set to 64-bit only.

1. Select the Office add-in setup project in solution explorer.
2. Go to Properties window and set `TargetPlatform` property to `x64`.

[image: MSI setup for Office add-ins]

Installing an add-in for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office, will require you to create two separate MSI packages. One for 32-bit and one for 64-bit.

Read more about creating MSI installers for Office COM/VSTO add-ins in the [Deploying a VSTO Solution Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022) article.

Comment: Thanks. In VS 2019 and 2022 you get different "properties" from context menu in solution view from the ones you get by pressing alt-enter. That got me confused.